# Window1 does not contain definition

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've got code where there's a string variable in MainWindow called "repeatNumber" -  there's also two buttons in MainWindow. btn2 should open up a new window 'otherwindow' that has the repeatNumber string in it and displays the picture.

'Window1' does not contain a definition for 'getRepeatedNumber' and no extension method 'getRepeatedNumber' accepting a first argument of type 'Window1' could be found.

Can anyone help me with this? Can this be fixed without using MVVM? Code bellow:

Mainwindow.cs

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private string repeatNumber;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            string[] assignments = new string[] { "https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/animals/48/Turtle.png", "https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/animals/48/Butterfly.png", "https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/animals/48/Dolphin.png", "https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/animals/48/Elephant.png", "https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/animals/48/Hippopotamus.png", "https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/animals/48/Panda.png" };
            Random rnd = new Random();

            string[] randomingArray = assignments.OrderBy(x => rnd.Next()).ToArray();


            List<Images> animals = new List<Images>();

            for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++)
            {
                if (i == 9)
                {
                    repeatNumber = randomingArray[i % randomingArray.Length];
                    animals.Add(new Images() { Source = repeatNumber, Number = i });
                }
                else if ((i % 9) == 0)
                {
                    animals.Add(new Images() { Source = repeatNumber, Number = i });
                }
                else
                {
                    animals.Add(new Images() { Source = randomingArray[i % rnd.Next(1, 5)], Number = i });
                }
                ItemsControl1.ItemsSource = animals;
            }
        }


        private void btn1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("test");
        }
        private void btn2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Window1 otherwindow = new Window1();
            otherwindow.Show();
            string value = otherwindow.getRepeatedNumber; <--- This line gives me the error
        }
    }

class Images
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public string Source { get; set; }
}
```

Mainwindow.xaml

```
<Grid>
        <ListBox x:Name="ItemsControl1">

            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>

                <ItemsPanelTemplate>

                    <UniformGrid Columns="5">
                    </UniformGrid>

                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="3" Width="Auto" Height="Auto">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Number}"/>
                            <Image Source="{Binding Source}" Margin="0,0,5,0"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

        </ListBox>
        <Grid>
            <Button x:Name="btn1" Click="btn1_Click" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="127,0,316,0" Content="Instruction"></Button>
            <Button x:Name="btn2" Click="btn2_Click" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="300,0,109,0" Content="Results" Width="74"></Button>

        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

Window1.cs

```
 public class Window2 : Window
{
    public string getRepeatedNumber { get; set; }

    public Window2(string repeatNumber)
    {
       getRepeatedNumber = repeatNumber;
    }
}
```

and Window1.xaml is just

```
<Grid>

</Grid>
```

Comment: `Window1 otherwindow = new Window1()`, it's not window 2.

Comment: If `Window2` has a `getRepeatedNumber()`, what makes you think you can use that on a `Window1`?

Comment: @ThomasWeller how can i achieve it then? I thought public Window2(string repeatNumber) in window2 would do the trick

Comment: Then create that window which allows repetition: `Window2 otherwindow = new Window2("something");`